# Probably a bad endcoding of outbound SMS message

Tags: sms, twilio, twilio-php

I just ran into an issue with a bad encoding of an outbound SMS messages. A few hours ago, everything worked just fine. Suddenly, I'm receiving a message like this:

```
@a@a@a@a@a@.@ @
@
@Z@a@j@ @m@ @ @n@ @s@ @V@ £a@ @k@o@m@e@n@t@ £Y@.@ @D@e@j@t@e@ @n@ @m@ @o@k@a@m£ü@i@t@e@ @v£@d£@t@ @p£Y@e@s@ @S@M@S@ @a@ £
@l@ @n@e@k@ @b@u@d@e@ @v@y@d@ @n@ @s@ @V@a£a@ @m@ @k@o@m@e@n@t@ £Y@e@m@.
```

I'm not sure what's wrong. There are some special Czech's characters like ěščř in that message, but a message is broken even without them.

In the Twilio's administration, messages look fine. UCS2 encoding is used. It shouldn't be a problem with my phone, because even my colleague has reported this issue with his one.

Does anybody have any idea what has broken? Some changes in API, or maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option with issues like the above, is to open a ticket with Twilio Support via the Twilio Console (upper right question mark) or via help@twilio.com with the respective SMS SID's, so they can help identify the issue.

Provide 3+ recent SMS SID's ([found in your SMS logs](https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/logs)), less then 48 hours old for them to identify patterns.

Alan